# Python Pandas converting datestring to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datestring in thew following format which is month/day/year and then time

```
print(df):
Date
6/06/20 4:41pm
6/06/20 5:41pm
```

I am trying to convert using `pd.to_datetime` and have used the following:

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%d%Y:%H:%M.%f')
```

but I cant match the format. Does anyone know the format for this particular sting? thank you very much!

Comment: Change the format to ``%m/%d/%y %H:%M.%p`` https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['6/06/20 4:41pm','6/06/20 5:41pm']})

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. as a follow up question. If I wanted to filter only rows for today how would I do that? I have tried `today = date.today()` and `tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)` and then `df= df[[df['Date']<tomorrow]]` but getting an `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date` error

Comment: Based on your latest comment. If wanted to select todays  date

    df.assign(Dates=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date)==pd.Timestamp('today')#Boolean selection

df[df.assign(Dates=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date)==pd.Timestamp('today')].dropna()#DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

you are missing part of the format

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M.%f')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer although seems to be still not picking it up. There is a space between the `year` and `hour` does that matter?

Comment: Yes, it should be the exact same

Comment: thanks for your help. I still couldnt get it working for some reason but appreaciate you help!